# Vagrant boxes as OpenStack images

Tags: openstack, vagrant

I have a node with OpenStack installed on it.

Currently I have one Ubuntu image file.

.

Can I use www.vagrantbox.es .box files for OpenStack?

I'm starting a cloud hosting company.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant now supports Docker a bit more.  That's designed for production environments more so than just vagrant + VirtualBox.

I don't see why you couldn't use provided boxes for OpenStack.. but you wouldn't want it running on VirtualBox (I/O read times are abysmal )

source : http://mitchellh.com/comparing-filesystem-performance-in-virtual-machines